# Can't read file from SSD

Tags: windows, ssd

I have a Crucial m4 SSD which is only a few months old.  I use this to run a virtual machine from and suddenly today the machine is unable to read one of the files needed to start up.  I have tried copying this file to another drive however the copy fails at 80% with the error.  So far I have tried:

- Using a different drive caddy - I use it as an external drive
- Running chkdsk - no errors found
- Trying it in a different PC - Exact same issue
- Copying using command prompt - fails with error Data Error (cyclic redundancy check)

I could really do with recovering this data, are there any tools / tips for this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your SSD is dying. You can try a completely free and great  app by Piriform called [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva).
Do it ASAP, after that replace this SSD. M4 are known to be good SSDs with low % of failures, just make sure to use the latest [firmware](http://www.crucial.com/support/firmware.aspx).